# Вывести имя DOM-элемента

Tags: javascript, dom

Добрый день!

```
 $launchParams = $("#launch").find("tbody tr td input");
 $launchParams.each(function(input){
    alert('input= ' + input);
}
```

**$launchParams** - массив контейнеров *input*.

Почему в цикле не выводится название тэгов DOM-элементов? в данном случае ведь предполагается вывод значений в текстовом контексте

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/dR8vM/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема, очевидно, в том, что  Функция each  в качестве коллбэкка принимает  функцию, у которой два параметра, а не один, следовательно, используя коллбэк с одним параметром, вы будете получать обращаться к индексу элемента, а не к самому элементу. Вероятно, это должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
var $launchParams = $("table").find("tbody tr td input");
$($launchParams).each(function(index, input) {
                          alert('input= ' + input);
                      });
```

Более того, поскольку при вызове вашего алерта происходит вызов функции **toString**, то разумеется вместо **<input type="text" />** вы получите что-нибудь такое: **[object HTMLInputElement]**

Comment: find вернет коллекцию jQuery, поэтому дополнительно оборачивать `$launchParams` в `$()` не надо.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov действительно, спасибо

Comment: Спасибо! А почему вернется именно *[object HTMLInputElement]*? Это же не массив, а просто объект, я не прав?